# different version of web services

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, iis, web

i have created a single website in iis and mapped it to my web service folder...

i want if i upgrade services, i dont want to overwrite the existing services version but rather create another folder in that main folder like v2

so suppose i have c:\MyService folder mapped to iis website which is accessible by localhost\MyService

having new version of services i want to deploy in c:\MyService\V2 which would be accessible by localhost\MyService\V2

web.config will be single on parent under c:\MyService\web.config

I tried this but this is not working for me in terms of when i try to access my latest web methods in V2, it says endpoint not found.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately `web.config` must be placed along `svc` file in the same folder.